# Vue: List rendering returns error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am simply trying to render a list in my view and I keep seeing the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "client" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
```

Here's **my view**:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 text-center" id="vueapp">
    <div class="table table-awaken" v-if="clients">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="client in clients">
                <td>{{ client }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my **vue instance**:

```
var vote = new Vue({
    el: "#vueapp",
    data: {
        clients: [
            { name: 'x' }
        ]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have `thead` and `tbody` that are not children of a `table` element. Browsers do interesting things when you break HTML rules like that.

See these docs which state that tbody and thead must be children of a table.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead

If you wrap those elements in a `table` element, it begins working. I am not sure if this is because of Vue or the browser.

Try this HTML instead:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 text-center" id="vueapp">
    <div class="table table-awaken">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="client in clients">
                <td>{{ client }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kg638x4f/

Comment: That did it!  I don't have any idea why I made it a `<div>` rather than `<table>`.  thanks!